# Selenium Error: sendKeys command not working properly. Can anyone resolve it?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I am trying to automate a site which asks the person about his details. In the Name of Applicant field we are supposed to write the full name.So clearly **[name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZhfo.png)** contains first name and last name and there must be space between first name and last name. But when I am trying to send the name using sendKeys command the characters after space (i.e last name) is not being sent and instead a lot of whitespaces are coming. I cant figure out the problem. Please, any help would be appreciated.

**Here is my code which I have written in eclipse IDE: **

```
package automation;

import java.time.Duration;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class residence {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ".\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    /*Store the current window handle */
    String parent_handle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.get("https://serviceonline.bihar.gov.in/resources/homePage/10/loginEnglish.htm");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'General')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//p[contains(text(),'Residential')]"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(("//div[@id='collapseOneOne']/div/p/a"))).click();
    
    for(String winHandle:driver.getWindowHandles()){
        if(!parent_handle.equals(winHandle))
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
    
    /* Write Gender accordingly.Default is Male(M).(F) and (T)*/
    char gender='M';
    WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//label[@for='17290_1']/input")));
    if(gender=='M')
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='17290_1']")).click();
    }
    else if(gender=='F')
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='17290_2']")).click();
    }
    else
    {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='17290_3']")).click();
    }
    
    WebElement obj=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='78250']"));
    
    /* I have also tried obj.sendKeys("Sumit Kumar") , this is also not working*/
    
    obj.clear();
    obj.sendKeys("Sumit",Keys.SPACE,"Kumar");
    obj = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='17287']"));
    obj.clear();
    obj.sendKeys("Name in Hindi with space ");
}  

}
```

***Here, are my screenshots of output:***

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZhfo.png)

Note:- Please note that it works in the adjacent text box as expected.

Comment: What happens if you actually type in "Sumit Kumar" in this web page, not using Selenium? What if you *paste* "Sumit Kumar" in the text box, rather than typing it? What if you split the sendKeys() call into multiple sendKeys() calls, each call sending part of the name? What if you run your code to just before the sendKeys() call, and then type in the name by hand? You want to isolate what behavior is caused by Selenium vs. just behavior of the website itself.

Comment: If I am typing "Sumit Kumar" in the webpage it works completely fine. When I paste "Sumit Kumar" in the text box then also it works completely fine. Also I have tried sending the strings one by one also but it doesnot work. Please help if possible.

Comment: One difference between typing and calling sendKeys() is timing, how fast the keys are entered. What if you call sendKeys() one letter at a time, pausing between each one?

Comment: Tried that too. Actually the problem lies in space, when I am sending space using Keys.space or " " then it is typing too many spaces. Do you think there is any workaround this problem?

Comment: Even when I am sending backspace to clear the name field, then also it is not working. Is there no one who could tell me how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you send Keys Command like this below , while entering name
I have Tested and it is able to enter name, there is a momentarily lag in focus as the textbox on the right side on the page is converting the entered name to Hindi, sending it like this below solved the issue

```
        obj.sendKeys("Sumit");
        obj.sendKeys(" ");
        obj.sendKeys("Kumar");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Your solution works fine. Can you tell me some other way by which I can send the string in one go?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to separate the string. You can send one String;

```
obj.sendKeys("Sumit Kumar");
```

Hope this helps!